# How to implement "click and don't wait for page reload" in Selenium2Library in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using [Selenium2Library](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html) in [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/). I want to click a link in a webpage but I don't want to wait for the page to reload.

When using [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.9.1) in Robot Framework, user can use this command:

```
| Click Link |  link text    |                      # A page is expected to load.
| Click Link |  another link |  don't wait |        # A page is not expected to load.
```

But I could not find the equivalent command in Selenium2Library.

How to implement "click and don't wait for page reload" in Selenium2Library in Robot Framework?

Comment: You accepted my answer (thanks!), so I'm curious which of those suggestions worked for you.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am using the method `Mouse Down followed by Mouse Up`. If I use `Click Link`, it will wait for the page to reload. If I use `Mouse Down followed by Mouse Up`, it will not wait for the page to reload. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the [Simulate](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Simulate) keyword to simulate a click on the element, rather than calling one of the click keywords. Looking through the code, I can't see where it does any sort of wait after doing the simulated event. You could also try writing your own keyword that calls [Mouse Down](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Mouse%20Down) followed by [Mouse Up](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Mouse%20Up).